# Adding words from a text file to a vector c++

Tags: c++, list, c++11, vector

I am trying to add each word from a file to a vector but if I make the size of the vector (500) and I only have 20 words in the file. The size of the vector is still considered 500. How do I fix this?

Am I doing this a bad way? Could this be made simpler?

```
void loadFile(string fileName)
{
    vector<string> fileContents(500);
    int p = 0;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(fileName);
    if (!file.is_open()) return;

    string word;
    while (file >> word)
    {
        fileContents[p] = word;
        p++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < fileContents.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << fileContents[i] << endl;
    }  
}
```

Comment: You should use `fileContents.push_back(word);`  instead of `fileContents[p] = word;` also change `vector<string> fileContents(500);` to `vector<string> fileContents;` and get rid of `p`

Comment: @drescherjm I tried that but when it goes to print out the file contents it doesn't print out anything? EDIT: NVM. I typed the command wrong.. that worked.. I thought I tried that but I guess I typed it wrong in the first place

Comment: @jake Did you get rid of `(500)`?

Comment: It works now. I think I might have left that in last time I tried that, and maybe that's why it wasn't working. @0x499602D2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use a more direct approach, copying immediately from the input stream.

```
std::vector<std::string> loadFile(std::string fileName) {
    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    assert(file);

    std::vector<std::string> fileContents;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(file), 
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), 
              std::back_inserter(fileContents));

    return fileContents;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@drescherjm in the comments gave me the correct answer.

```
void loadFile(string fileName)
{
    vector<string> fileContents;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(fileName);
    if (!file.is_open()) return;

    string word;
    while (file >> word)
    {
        fileContents.push_back(word);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < fileContents.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << fileContents[i] << endl;
    }  
}
```